# Should WFC service project contain database model

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, wcf

I'm developing a web application that is going to use WCF as a buisness logic provider.

My solution consists of these 4 projects:
- ASP.NET MVC project
- UnitTests project
- ProjectCore - C# library with code first entity framework database
- WCF Service Application

My question is related to the WCF service and database model location.

**Which option should I use (and why):**
- Move code first EF db to WCF service application project?
- Add WCF service to ProjectCore?
- Leave it as it is in different projects?

I have maintained one big project where all WCF services were included in one Core library and it worked well but I wonder what you may suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Practically it would work everywhere, but the right approach is a DAL(Data Access Layer) project.

So add another project containing your DAL objects and methods. This might seem a little unnecessary for an EntityFramework connected db, but for other type of more complex connectors(where you need to right your own queries) DAL is a life saver layer. Hence it's a good practice to get used to it.